# Run some code asynchronously with timeout

Tags: c#, multithreading, timeout

I want to run a block of code (or method) in C#. In this block I use Web Service method. I want to run it asynchronously (to avoid freeze application) with time out. My code is:

```
SmsSender s = new SmsSender();

dataGrid.ItemsSource = 
    s.GetAllInboxMessagesDataSet().Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

before this I use thread.Abort. finally **I find out that thread.Abrot is evil**

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C# 4.5 you can do it like that:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(3000); // Set timeout

var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Working...
    }

}, cts.Token);
```

Comment: Thank you. your code seems good but when change 2000 to 60000 ctc.Cancel runs before work completed! my work will complete approximately in 30 seconds. +1 for your effort

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to the problem (not to freeze the main thread). My solution is to create one Task and within to create a second task for which i wait. The wrapper task is not blocked by wait or join and so the main thread is not blocked. With events i can notify the caller, that the **worker** task has timed out or not. The code looks like this:

```
// create asynchronous task. in order not to block the calling thread,
// create and start another task in this one and wait for its completion
var synchronize = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
{                   
    var worker = new System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
    {
        // do something work intensive
    });                 
    var workCompleted = worker.Wait(10000 /* timeout */);
    if (!workCompleted)
    {
        // worker task has timed-out
    }
});
```